# 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit while building an app where i used db.json, api.http

Tags: reactjs, api, github, netlify

I was building an react app where i used db.json and used local server like api.http for GET, POST, DELETE, PUT. I deployed that code in github and trying to publish it in netlify. i am getting this error Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2.

1. code is running properly on local.
2. i used CI= npm run build and undated environment to CI false.

how to resolve this issue?

Error message
9:24:02 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: CI= npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
9:24:02 PM: ​
9:24:02 PM:   Error location
9:24:02 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
9:24:02 PM:   CI= npm run build
9:24:02 PM: ​
9:24:02 PM:   Resolved config
9:24:02 PM:   build:
9:24:02 PM:     command: CI= npm run build
9:24:02 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
9:24:02 PM:     environment:
9:24:02 PM:       - CI
9:24:02 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
9:24:02 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
9:24:04 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
9:24:04 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site

I tried to local run, app is working.